# How to use CloudFromation to update a single API Gateway consists of multiple services

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have a single api gateway consists of several services's endpoints (let's say service A, B, C, D). When a single service A update, I would like to dynamically update the api gateway for service A only and keep service B, C, D unchanged. And I have a maven plugin to generate swagger file for each service.

To make this work, I have to solutions:

1. Use AWS CLI to do api gateway update in **merge** mode by swagger file of service A and do redeployment.
2. Merge all swagger files of service A, B, C, D to a single swagger file and upload this single swagger file to S3 bucket. Then I can use CloudFormation template to create api gateway (with S3BodyLocation to my swagger file in previous step) and redeploy.

My question is, is there an easier way that I can use CloudFormation to update api gateway for single service like aws cli without need to merge all services' swagger files? Or any other solution that can achieve my goal? If not, which of my solution is better? Thank you.

PS. I am also curious about how people using single api gateway for microservices, for me it looks like there is no way to avoid merging multi swagger files from all services before using it to create api gateway.

Answer (score 1):

With `AWS::Serverless::Api`, you should use `DefinitionBody` property.
 Here comes excellent example [Realworld-serverless](https://github.com/awslabs/realworld-serverless-application/blob/1fcdbefd6869c0a32489f2eb25f340b5f65af261/backend/sam/app/api.template.yaml#L31-L36).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know I should use DefinitionBody, but my pain point is my swagger files are spread out in multi services, so I have to merge them into a single swagger file before I can use it in DefinitionBody Location. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid doing this...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at SAM which will help you to generate your API Gateway a little simpler than traditional CloudFormation but will still generate the CloudFormation stack for you.

Take a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried SAM before, but like traditional CF, it still requires my provide the definition body/uri for the whole api gateway, which means I still have to merge all service swagger files together.

Comment: Alternatively you could reconstruct it using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-resource.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html. This would not require merging, but would require you to develop it from fresh.